# I have to create a basic Bank Menu and I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around it

Tags: python, menu, bank

I'm trying to figure out where to go from here, I know I have to have an accumulator somewhere in there to show the current balance of the the user.  I'm not quite sure how to implement it, as well as keeping it persistent when the user wants to do other things like 'withdrawal' and other stuff.

I've also tried to somehow make the program terminate itself, but have been having a hard time figuring out that too.  I've even tried taking a break from it and looking at it again just to see if I could come up with something new.  Not too sure what else to do.

EDIT: I can see that I've been confusing a few people.  This was what I was asked to do: I was asked to create a basic program that displays a bank account menu where each option would do these things: Open Account would greet the new user and gives them the option to make an initial deposit to create the account. Deposit would just update the account's balance. Withdraw would update the account by withdrawing the amount the user would ask to take out of the balance. Balance would just display the user's balance, and exit would quit the program

```
balance = 0.0000


print("Welcome to Sys Financial Bank!  New clients must open a new account to continue properly.")

print("""1) New Account
2) Deposit
3) Withdraw
4) Balance
5) Exit""")
option = int(input("Please input the number corresponding with the option in the menu: "))

if option == 1:
    option_1 = float(input("Input initial deposit amount to create account: $"))
    balance =+ option_1

elif option == 2:
    option_2 = float(input("Input deposit amount: $"))
    balance = option_1 + option_2

elif option == 3:
    option_3 = float(input("Input withdrawal amount: $"))
    balance = option_1 - option_3

elif option == 4:
    print("Your current balance is: ", balance)

else:
    import sys
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you're having trouble, but what is your actual question?

Comment: I was asked to create a basic program that displays a bank account menu where each option would do these things: Open Account would greet the new user and gives them the option to make an initial deposit to create the account.  Deposit would just update the account's balance.  Withdraw would update the account by withdrawing the amount the user would ask to take out of the balance.  Balance would just display the user's balance, and exit would quit the program.

Comment: You still do not seem to have a question. A description of your homework assignment is not a question. If you are totally lost, you should be rereading the relevant portions of your textbook and talking to your professor.

Comment: Already have and am doing so to see if I missed something in the book, thanks for trying to help though! :D

Comment: You're overcomplicationg this by using too much variables. Get rid of `option_1`, `option_2` and `option_3`. Use `balance` for the balance and reuse a variable named `amount` for every other amount of money you need in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but i am going to guess.

You want a program that while the user doesn't hit five doesn't exit, right?

The way I'd do it

```
from sys import exit
balance = 0.0000
print("Welcome to Sys Financial Bank!  New clients must open a new account to continue properly.")
print("""1 New Account \n2) Deposit \n3) Withdraw \n4) Balance \n5) Exit""")
try:
    while True:
        option = int(input("Please input the number corresponding with the option in the menu: "))
        if option == 1:
            option_1 = float(input("Input initial deposit amount to create account: $"))
            balance += option_1
        elif option == 2:
            option_2 = float(input("Input deposit amount: $"))
            balance += option_2

        elif option == 3:
            option_3 = float(input("Input withdrawal amount: $"))
            balance -= option_3

        elif option == 4:
            print("Your current balance is: ", balance)

        elif option == 5:
            exit('Have a nice day')
except ValueError:
    print('Input a number')
```

However this does not ensure "New clients must open a new account to continue properly". Not that it matters. but if you must. then execute the option 1 prior to the while

Comment: I'm very sorry for confusing you.  I was asked to create a basic program that displays a bank account menu where each option would do these things: Open Account would greet the new user and gives them the option to make an initial deposit to create the account. Deposit would just update the account's balance. Withdraw would update the account by withdrawing the amount the user would ask to take out of the balance. Balance would just display the user's balance, and exit would quit the program.  I found the instructions myself a bit vague.

Comment: I believe my answer above solves your problem... but you won't learn unless you try to do it yourself

Comment: I agree, hence why I'm not going to look at it until I've asked some help from other places and dug more into the past material I've learned to figure it out myself.  Then I'll look at yours to see where I went wrong or where I went right.